# how to switch between multiple threads in android

Tags: android

i am new to android.in my application i create one activity that contains 3 different handlers and threads. Create 3 threads in Android , with each thread playing a different video.
   The videos should be of say 5 mins duration. 
   At End of every on 1 minute, the thread pauses the video and the context
is switched to 
   the next thread. And now the next thread plays for 1 min and then context
switch to 3rd third thread.
   This cycle continues till the entire video is played.
thanks in advance

Comment: Thanku lalit, for giving valuable advice.i can't understand clearlly.please give the sample code for how to switch between three threads and making synchronization between them.
and how to play the video file in videoview in specific time.for ex,if the video length is 6mins.i want to play the video file for 1min.and pause the video.after some time,i can play the video from 1min1sec and so on.........

Answer (score 1):

Just manage the `Runnables` with `Handler`.

To start a `Runnable`,

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable1, 1000);
```

To stop a `Runnable`,

```
 handler.removeCallbacks(runnable1);
```

So, in your case if you want to manage all `Runnables`, you can just switch between all the 3 `Runnables`, using `Handler`.